# Any way to view Microsoft Publisher files in Mac OS X

Tags: ms-office

I'm trying to view a MS Publisher file without running a Windows virtual machine. Any way to do that? It's ok if it doesn't render 100% accurately.

Comment: I generally don't recommend cross-over for general use, but in MS Publisher case, if you have a copy of the app, it runs fairly well in crossover emulation. They have a free trial and you can check other versions for compatibility here... http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your idea is only to **READ** and never to edit, I would suggest that you convert the file into PDF format using any of the thousands free converters out there, for example:

> http://www.publishertopdf.com/

So you don't need a license of Microsoft Publisher neither CrossOver.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Crossover/Wine. Not sure how well Publisher runs personally, but I know that the rest of Office 2003 (if that's the version that you're using) works perfectly (and that's using the free version they gave out a couple of years ago, I imagine it's only gotten better since).

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for converting first. If you convert the file using Zamzar online, then you can open the file as a PDF on your Mac. You could also ask the sender to save in an alternative format if that's an option for you. For more information and help plus all the great alternatives to Publisher for Mac, check this post:
http://machow2.com/publisher-for-mac/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.